# 2 line breaks automatically added

Tags: php, windows, macos, line-breaks

I code in php, and put the code on the server. But my peers pointed out I put the Line breaks too many times. And with his pc ,I looked through the code which I already posted on the server. (I use mac.) 
There are a lot of extra line breaks added automatically.
However I didn't put that many line breaks. I guess If I put one line break, something would converts it to two line breaks somehow. In my environment, I can see exactly the same as I type.
I guess there could be some compatibility problems between his and mine.

I use :
Mac os x, SublimeText2, Yummy FTP.

He uses :
Windows 7, SublimeText2, WinSCP.

I searched but I couldn't find exact answer.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour once again?

Comment: Maybe something relating to `CSS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused be different line ending. Mac OS X uses Unix convention of a new line, Windows uses carriage return, linefeed at the end of lines.

Open a file in a hex editor to see these characters.

You can convert the text to the platforms convention. There are tools for this. Some editors can handle the different endings.